# Print a random sentence from a list?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to output a random sentence from a list and then output it as text. How do I do that? Currently I have this code:

```
if(message.content.startsWith('!')){
   let sentenc = Array('Hello', 'Whats Up')
   shuffle(sentenc)
   messages.channel.send(sentenc)
}
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Consider using an array of words, then you can sort them, then join them

Comment: Please stick to English when asking a question as in this large community not everyone might be able to understand German.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
if(message.content.startsWith('!')){
    let sentenc = ['Hello', 'Whats Up', '2', '3', '4']
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * sentenc.length) // Gives you a random position number from 0 to your Array length
    message.channel.send(sentenc[random]) // Sends a message of your Array while random is always between 0 and your Array length
}
```

See the [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to shuffle the array and then join the array with spaces in between.

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) thread on how to shuffle an array and joining it with spaces is simply done by `array.join(" ")`.